# LoadLibraryExW is not loading the language-specific MUI version of the application

Tags: windows, winapi, material-ui, localization

When localizing applications in Windows, you provide your application:

- `C:\Program Files\Contoso\Grobber.exe`

and you supply various dll (with a `.mui` extension) in child folders that contain localized resources:

- `C:\Program Files\Contoso\Grobber.exe`
- `C:\Program Files\Contoso\en-US\Grobber.exe.mui`
- `C:\Program Files\Contoso\en-CA\Grobber.exe.mui`
- `C:\Program Files\Contoso\fr-CAca\Grobber.exe.mui`
- `C:\Program Files\Contoso\fr-FR\Grobber.exe.mui`
- `C:\Program Files\Contoso\es-US\Grobber.exe.mui`
- `C:\Program Files\Contoso\fr-DE\Grobber.exe.mui`

And according to Microsoft, and [their documentation for localizing an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/mui-system-settings-application-sample), if you are running on Windows Vista or later, you are supposed to be able to call **LoadLibrary**, and Windows will transparently select the appropriate file out of the appropriate folder based on the current locale of the system:

```
// 1. Basic application obtains access to the proper resource container 
    // for standard Win32 resource loading this is normally a PE module - use LoadLibraryEx
    // LoadLibraryEx is the preferred alternative for resource modules as used below because it
    // provides increased security and performance over that of LoadLibrary
    HMODULE resContainer = LoadLibraryExW(HELLO_MODULE_CONTRIVED_FILE_PATH,NULL,LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE | LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
    if(!resContainer)
    {
        swprintf_s(displayBuffer,SUFFICIENTLY_LARGE_ERROR_BUFFER,L"FAILURE: Unable to load the resource container module, last error = %d.",GetLastError());
        MessageBoxW(NULL,displayBuffer,L"HelloMUI ERROR!",MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return 1; // exit
    }
```

Except when i run it, it simply loads my base executable, rather than:

- C:\Program Files\Contoso\en-US\Grobber.exe.mui

My pseudo-code:

```
HMODULE resContainer = LoadLibraryExW("C:\Program Files\Contoso\Grobber.exe", NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE | LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);

int n = LoadStringW(resContainer, SInternalRequestsMUI, buffer, bufferLen);

MessageBox(0, "TestApp", buffer, MB_OK);
```

returns the **unlocalized** string - the one in the [Language Neutral (LN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/muiload/nf-muiload-loadmuilibrarya) file.

**Note**: I don't understand how Windows can be expected to psychically know that i want it to load some **other** library, rather than the one i specified, but that's what the documentation says.

So what am i missing? It's supposed to be loading a different file, found in a `language-COUNTRY` folder, based on the OS's current language. Why is it not loading one?

### Setting a custom language

[Microsoft also notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/mui-application-specific-settings-sample-vista) that your Windows Vista or newer app can override the system default language, and instead specify another language to load into your application by calling **SetThreadPreferredUILanguages**:

> ### [MUI: Application-Specific Settings Sample (Windows Vista)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/mui-application-specific-settings-sample-vista)

```
    // the following line of code is supported on Windows Vista and forward
    if(!SetThreadPreferredUILanguages(MUI_LANGUAGE_NAME,userLanguagesMultiString,&langCount) || langCount == 0)
    {
        swprintf_s(displayBuffer,SUFFICIENTLY_LARGE_ERROR_BUFFER,L"FAILURE: Unable to set the user defined, last error = %d.",GetLastError());
        MessageBoxW(NULL,displayBuffer,L"HelloMUI ERROR!",MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return 1; // exit
    }
```

They also note that pre-Vista the system would not perform this automatic searching for you, and instead you had to call an alternative to **LoadLibrary** called **LoadMUILibrary** that would do the searching work:

> [**MUI: Application-Specific Settings Sample (Pre-Windows Vista)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/mui-application-specific-settings-sample-pre-vista)
>
> ```
>  resContainer = LoadMUILibraryW(HELLO_MODULE_CONTRIVED_FILE_PATH,MUI_LANGUAGE_NAME,0);
> ```

Those are interesting tidbits. But since i'm not using Windows XP or earlier, they don't really matter. And i only care about the default system language - not overriding it.

Comment: of course windows will not and can not load mui dll inside `LoadLibraryExW`. mui can be loaded when you try access resourse from this dll. this done inside `LoadString` call for instance. api which do this - `LdrLoadAlternateResourceModuleEx`

Comment: so mui will be loaded not inside call `LoadLibraryExW` but inside call `LoadStringW`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> LoadLibraryExW is not loading the language-specific MUI version of the
> application

it and not must do this. and can not - because `LoadLibraryExW` not take *Language ID* as parameter.

and you note it by self

> *I don't understand how Windows can be expected to psychically know that i want it to load some other library, rather than the one i
> specified, but that's what the documentation says.*

the *MUI* dll is loaded during call to FindResourceEx/LoadString - example of call graph:

[image]

also we can do this direct by call api from ntdll

```
EXTERN_C
NTSYSAPI
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
LdrLoadAlternateResourceModuleEx (
    _In_ HMODULE hModule,
    _In_ LANGID LangId,
    _Out_ HMODULE* pAltResourceDllHandle,
    _Out_ PSIZE_T ViewSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

MSDN [says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/mui-resource-management):

> Association of files uses a checksum reflected in resource configuration data contained in all associated files. The resource loader uses the checksum to verify that the files hold the same version of the required resources. It also validates the language in the language-specific file with its folder name. The loader does not load a resource file if the appropriate association is not established.

This means you have to pass the correct switches to the resource compiler or use the MUIRCT tool from the SDK to please the MUI part of the loader.

If you look at the system files shipped with Windows in a resource editor you will see a magic MUI resource with undocumented contents...

Answer (score 0):

Did your [LN File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/mui-resource-management#resource-configuration-data) in the ***Grobber.exe*** configure correctly?
According to [LN File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/mui-resource-management#resource-configuration-data) which is referred as ***.dll** in the document, you need t[o associate an LN file with its language-specific files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/resource-utilities). And then when [Loading Language Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/loading-language-resources), *Many resource loading functions have been modified to load resources from language-specific resource files automatically, treating resources as if they are contained in the LN file.*

Comment: [The loader does not load a resource file if the appropriate association is not established.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/mui-resource-management#features-of-the-mui-resource-technology) The appropriate association includes a main checksum and service checksums which *are used to determine the appropriate version of the language-specific resource file to load and are calculated based on the localizable resources in the file*.